# how to creare Master Page in an existing MasterPage

Tags: asp.net, nested, master-pages

the software contains one functional master page which has many ASPX file under these  master page   and i want to add another main Master Page above the existing one , does any one help me how to do ? when i try to add Masterpage by selecting Previous Masterpage  and run , it generate error related to the content place holders.

Comment: don't forget to accept an answer if it helped you, as a basic courtesy to others...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are called "nested master pages", here is an official walkthrough, but you can google the term for a tons more like it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb547109.aspx